# get nan when using tf.reduce_prod, maybe due to tensorflow floating point precision

Tags: tensorflow, floating-point, precision

I have a tensorflow model which runs fine when using log(x), where I do a tf.reduce_sum along an axis. But when I change to no log, and take tf.reduce_prod, I end up with nan for parameter values. The logic seems perfectly fine to me. I tried casting all values to tf.float64, but no difference. 
the beginning:

```
log_prob_v = self.poisson._log_prob(v_value)
log_prob_c = self.bernoulli._log_prob(c_value)
log_prob_c_v = tf.add(log_prob_c, log_prob_v)
log_prob_c_v = tf.cast(log_prob_c_v, tf.float64)
```

adding log prob works:

```
reduce_sum_log_prob = tf.reduce_sum(log_prob_c_v, axis=-1)
reduce_sum_log_prob = tf.reshape(reduce_sum_log_prob, shape=[self.N, 1])
```

multiplying prob fails:

```
prob_c_v = tf.exp(log_prob_c_v)        
reduce_prob = tf.reduce_prod(prob_c_v, axis=1)
reduce_prob = tf.reshape(reduce_prob, shape=[self.N, 1])
log_reduce_prob = tf.log(reduce_prob)
```

Anyone have any idea what can be causing the difference?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Are you saying the logarithm of the sum of some numbers does not get NaN but the product of the numbers does? This can happen with 0 and ∞. Their sum is ∞, and the logarithm of that is ∞. The product of 0 and ∞ is NaN.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It's a floating point precision problem. I am surprised even float64 couldn't take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting intermediate underflow: if there is a log-probability that is < -744 (or < -103 if using 32-bit floats), then its `exp` will be `0.0`. This will make the product `0.0` as well, and taking the `log` of `0.0` should give negative infinity, but perhaps tensorflow is doing something funny to return a NaN.

By summing the log-probabilities directly, you avoid this problem.